# ActiveMQ prioritisation strange behaviour

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I push the messages in a  queue with different priorities. I can see that the JMSpriority header is correctly set using the ActiveMQ web interface.

Here is my test. I first push big amount of messages with low priority in the queue. We have a slow consumer "pattern" so all messages starts to accumulates and are properly enqueued. KahaDB is used for storage.
Then I push high priority messages.

The issue is that as long as I don't click on the queue to display the messages in the activeMQ web interface the messages are not sorted, and high priority messages are not dispatched to the consumers. As soon as I click on the queue, I immediately see a page refresh that results in the proper sorting, seeing high priority message on the top. This messages will be then dispatched asap and "disappear" from the enqueued message list, as expected.

So obviously there is something wrong somewhere since prioritisation involve this manual step. I I used the configuration as described here https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.

I already think about a workaround using JMX to force a queue sort, but really I'd like to avoid this !

I'am using AMQ version 5.15, spring and camel.

Comment: Did you disable caching and reduce the pre-fetch, as shown in the documentation you linked? Respecting message priorities with slow consumers is often a challenge, because the priority selection and caching mechanisms are somewhat in conflict with one another.

Comment: Yes I set :
prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false" queuePrefetch="1"
I also noticed this old parameter that I kept expireMessagesPeriod="0"

Comment: With the documented settings, I find I can produce a thousand messages with priority 4, then one with priority 9, no consumers running. Then I connect a consumer, and I get the priority-9 message first. Do you see a different sequence of events with this test? Does the problem depend on some particular pattern of production and consumption in your system? The priority mechanism does seem to be basically working for me.

Comment: I did your test. publish low prio message, publish high prio message. Start consumers.
In this case indeed it worked well.
I let the system run to consume all high prio messages. After that  the queue still contained thousands of low prio messages. I added then few high prio messages. It worked but only after a while. I had to wait about 30 minutes. I have to see if it can be related to some kahadb timings / checkpoints or something else. Thanks for you help in any case

Comment: I suspect it's just the result of paging behaviour. You might need set `maxPageSize` for the queue to a much lower of much higher value. Depending on the circumstances, either might help, for different reasons. Or just use different queues for different priorities ;)

Comment: @greg, you have reduced `queuePrefetch` as per KevinBoone's suggestion and you are using `queuePrefetch=1`. I would suggest to use `queuePrefetch=0`. I have had similar issue in the past where I was using `queuePrefetch=1` which was the reason behind each consumer working on a task and having one more message lined up for that particular consumer only. This pre-fetched message will be the next message for that consumer regardless new high priority message in the queue. So if you have 1000 consumers, each will have one message pre-fetched and new high priority message won't be picked up ASAP.

Comment: Thanks I will try with 0 !!